# Processing large text file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have 4GB+ text files (csv format) and I want to process this file using linq in c#.

I run complex linq query after load csv and convert to class?

but file size is 4gb although application memory double size of file.

how can i process (linq and new result) large files?

Thanks

Comment: What version of .NET are you using

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of loading whole file into memory, you could read and process the file line-by-line.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // analize line here
        // throw it away if it does not match
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

If you need to run complex queries against the data in the file, the right thing to do is to load the data to database and let DBMS to take care of data retrieval and memory management.

Comment: What about if all Text if in a Single Line without a Carriage Return ?

Comment: @Cody - I assumed that csv file is not a single line file.

Comment: Then you would process the whole line as a stream of bytes, rather than a stream of lines.

Comment: @cody then it's either one record that would potentially have to be handled at once since you can't know up front what fields are going to be in the lin query or an unusual record delimiter has been used and OP would very likely have included that since it's a crucial detail

Comment: I should load all data to memory for run linq query and create new result?

Comment: @oguzh4n - if you want to use LINQ - yes, you need to load to memory. Another option is to create a kind of LINQ-to-File wrapper, that would fetch line by line, turn line into an object run predicates on the objects and select or throw away the line. Anyway, reading line-by-line is the only way to save the memory.

Comment: I run complex linq query (self join and one more predicate)

Comment: @oguzh4n - if you run complicated self-join queries, you have to load the data to the memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is good way...
[CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Linq2CSV.aspx)

Comment: [link](http://i51.tinypic.com/5dphtg.png) problem is this
Read byte 500MB but memory 2GB

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you could use [Clay](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek6DynamicMalleableEnjoyableExpandoObjectsWithClay.aspx) and then write a method that returns an IEnumerable line for line and that makes code like the below possible

```
from record in GetRecords("myFile.csv",new []{"Foo","Bar"},new[]{","})
where record.Foo == "Baz"
select new {MyRealBar = int.Parse(record.Bar)
```

the method to project the CSV into a sequence of Clay objects could be created like:

```
 private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetRecords(
                    string filePath,
                    IEnumerable<string> columnNames, 
                    string[] delimiter){
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                yield break;
            var columns = columnNames.ToArray();
            dynamic New = new ClayFactory();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath)){
                var columnLength = columns.Length;
                string line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null){
                    var record = New.Record();
                    var fields = line.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    if(fields.Length != columnLength)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                                 "fields count does not match column count");
                    for(int i = 0;i<columnLength;i++){
                        record[columns[i]] = fields[i];
                    }
                    yield return record;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for advice,
I tried this solution but it's very slow and has same memory issue.

Comment: @oguzh4n oh I delibarately did not take speed into account since you didn't mention that in your post. I'd preferre readability (in this case of the call site) over speed any day. About the memory issues. If you could be more precise about those they can be fixed. This does not have to hold more than one line of the text file and one clay object at a time (and a bit) so what ever memory issues the draft above has they can be fixed